# How to use imageList Control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, imagelist

I have some images that i added to imageList Cotrol manually.
Now i need remove thart images from imageList depending on the key index and set as panel backgroud.

How should i do it

Comment: you want to remove some images based on their index and add them ass background of your panel?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Images` that you added in Image list are added to the [ImageList.ImageCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.aspx), so it is collection type then you can use most of the collection methods.

Use the Images property to add, remove and access the image to display in background of panel.
[Add(key,image)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h1kxkbx.aspx)
[Remove()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.remove.aspx)
[RemoveAt()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.removeat.aspx)
[RemoveByKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.removebykey.aspx)

Check the example on the [ImageList Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) documentation to understand that how pragmatically use all of these methods.

**Add Image:**

```
imageList1.Images.Add("pic1", Image.FromFile("c:\\mypic.jpg"));
```

**Remove Image from collection:**

```
imageList1.Images.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
imageList1.Images..RemoveByKey("pic1");
```

To access images, get image from the imagecollection

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[0];
```

or

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images["pic1"];
```

Comment: I try using panel1.BackgroundImage = imageList1.Images[0]; but the image is not shown properly,do i need to do use some other method along this one?

Comment: check panel's `BackgroundImageLayout` property for image view settings..  image list can store maximum 256x256 pixel image.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Images` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.images.aspx) of the `ImageList` control.

The [`ImageList.ImageCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.aspx) object that it returns provides all the methods you need to manipulate the images in the list, including `Add` and `Remove` methods.

You can find instructions on setting the background of a `Panel` control here: [How to: Set the Background of a Windows Forms Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tkhesczs.aspx)

Comment: i try using this method but it returns void imageList1.Images.RemoveByKey("nameOfImage")

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to return `void`. That's the signature of the method. See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist.imagecollection.removebykey.aspx). It doesn't return success or failure.

Answer (score 0):

i am using imagelist in list view.

let say i have three images in imagelist and want to delete 2 image in it.

i used code

```
    imagelist.Images.RemoveAt(2);
```

code is deleting 2nd image but after that 3 image is bot visible although it is there

Comment: my prob lem is imagelist is not auto refreshing