# Put image on dynamically created button

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I have dynamically created a button, now I need to put image on it , which is saved on my HDD. I tried doing

```
btndynamic.image=((Sytem.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("button.Image")));
```

But it gave me an error :
The name 'resouces' does not exist in the current context

Then I tried :

```
btndynamic.image=Image.FromFile(@"images\image1.jpg");
```

again gave me an error:
Verify that the file exists in the specified location.

So what am I doing wrong, or is there any other way.

Comment: How you create and initialize `resources` variable?

Comment: did you add your images to the ressources of your project? If so, how is this ressource named? Also, for the second option you give a relative path, do you really have an `image` folder in your `debug` directory?

Comment: About `Image.FromFile` remember that the code directory is not the same as the sturtup directory

Comment: Try using the absolute path, like c:\yourimage.jpg

Comment: @ppetrov yes image is added to resource file, what do you mean by how is this resource named. For the second part I have a images folder in my project.

Comment: @animaonline if I use absolute path then it would be a problem if I run a setup on other machine

Comment: Of course it would be, but you can start by testing with an absolute path, in order to verify that it is in fact working.

Comment: @animaonline yes its working if I put absolute path.

Comment: then , you've got to make sure your relative path is correct, start by verifying Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ImageList` control on your form. This control is not visible at runtime and lets you add the images you need to use in your form later.
You add this control on your form exactly the same way you add a button, you can find it in the toolbox under the `Components` tab.
In the properties, you'll see an `Images` property, you just have to edit it, and you'll see a dialog box where you can add image ressources from your disk. Just add what you need and set the properties (like a key) for each image added.

Then all you have to do is to get the image you need for your button from this control:

you have 2 ways of doing it, by using an index

```
dynamicButton.Image = imageList1.Images[index];
```

or a key

```
dynamicButton.Image = imageList1.Images["your_image_key"];
```

that way your images can be included in your assembly, and you don't have to worry about the paths

if you need more info about it, try these links:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/9cda50a5-8eba-4e1f-87ee-7486352c0907

[How to use imageList Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587269/how-to-use-imagelist-control)

Comment: can you please explain a bit never used imagelist control. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the image to your resources then assign the button Image property to it like this:

```
NewButton.Image = global::YOURPROJECTNAME.Properties.Resources.YOURRESOURCENAME;
```