# Replace Images at the Top of ImageList and ListView

Tags: c#, listview, imagelist

I will load say 10 images in imagelist and list View. then later, I want to replace the first 5 (top 5 in the list). But The new images are always added at the bottom of the list in the display.

```
    Initialize_ListView()
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
           AddItemTo_ListView(i);
        }

Now I later use this code to replace the top 5
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
           ImageAndThumb imgObj = new ImageAndThumb(output);
           Replace(imgObj , i)
        }


   private void Initialize_ListView()
    {
        this.imageList1.Images.Clear();
        this.listView1.Clear();
        this.listView1.View = View.SmallIcon;
        this.imageList1.ImageSize = new Size(75, 80);
        this.listView1.SmallImageList = this.imageList1;
    }

    private void AddItemTo_ListView(int index)
    {
        ImageAndThumb imgObj = new ImageAndThumb(output);
        ImageAndThumbLst.Add(imgObj);

         this.imageList1.Images.Add(ImageAndThumbLst[index].Thumb);

        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.ImageIndex = index;
        this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
    }


    private void Replace(ImageAndThumb obj, int indx)
    {
        ImageAndThumbLst[indx] = obj;          
        this.imageList1.Images[indx] = ImageAndThumbLst[indx].Thumb;
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
        item.ImageIndex = indx;           
        this.listView1.Items[indx]=item;      
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15907754/c-sharp-imagelist-wont-display-images

Answer (score 0):

For anyone making the same mistake, I was creating a new item in he replace function which is unnecessay.   The new replace function should look like this

```
private void Replace(ImageAndThumb obj, int indx)
{
    ImageAndThumbLst[indx] = obj;          
    this.imageList1.Images[indx] = ImageAndThumbLst[indx].Thumb;       
     listView1.Refresh();   
}
```