# how to add an image to specific index of imagelist?

Tags: c#, imagelist

c# visualstudio

i want to copy index[0] of imagelist1 to index[0] of imagelist2 as a backup.
how should i do that?

Comment: [How to use imageList Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587269/how-to-use-imagelist-control)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use imageList Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587269/how-to-use-imagelist-control)

Comment: There is no real conceivable way to get this wrong.  Maybe you forgot to delete imageList1.Images.Clear().  Post the code that doesn't work instead of code that you don't need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean this..? Make sure you make use of System.Collection.Generics.

```
// Declaring your lists   
List<Image> imagelist1 = new List<Image>();
List<Image> imagelist2 = new List<Image>();

// Let's say you filled these list here.

// Copy image with index 0 to the second imagelist.
imagelist2.Add(imagelist1[0]);
```

Comment: tnx for you answer but imagelist(imagelist2) doesn't have .Add attribute.and i cant declare list as you say.what should i do?

Comment: You need to use "System.Collections.Generic", to declare it the way I did. How did you declare your lists?

Comment: AddRange is also possible.